# Having trouble getting the value when converting a void pointer to a struct

Tags: c++, struct, operating-system, void-pointers

I am passing in a void pointer that was converted from a struct into a function topTwo.  When I cast it back and try to get data from the struct I get the address instead.  What am I doing wrong?
In this function I am trying to get `localStruct->number` to return 1 and instead it is returning the address.

```
 void  *topTwo(void *p)
 {
  struct Variables * localStruct;
  localStruct= (struct Variables *) p;
  cout<<localStruct->number<<endl;
  int  z = long(localStruct->number);
  cout<<z<<endl;
}
```

Here is the struct

```
struct Variables{
 int largestNum;
 int secondLargestNum;
 int number;
};
```

Here is the main function that passes in the data.

```
int main() 
{
    Variables *vars;
    vars= new struct Variables();
    vars->largestNum=0;
    vars->secondLargestNum=0;
    vars->number=0;
    pthread_t  tid[5];
    for(int  i=0; i<5; i++)
    {                                   
       vars->number=i;
       cout<<vars->number<<endl;                                               
       void * sVoid;
       sVoid = (void *) &vars;
       pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, topTwo,(void *) sVoid);
       pthread_join(tid[i], NULL);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
sVoid = (void *) &vars;  // this is a `struct Variables**`
```

to:

```
sVoid = (void *) vars;
```

Comment: Thanks, for some reason the example I was going off of have the & in it

Comment: The cast really isn't needed.